# Table Alignment (3 tables)

Tags: tables

I have three tables sides by sides and I want to align their horizontal lines together to be on the same level. How do I do that?

[image]

This is my LaTeX overleaf code:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
        \footnotesize
            \begin{tabular}[t]{p{2.5cm}c c}
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Group A}}\\
                \toprule
                Agitator speed (rpm) & $U\ (\frac{BTU}{hr\ ft^2\ ^\circ F})$\\
                &\\
                \midrule
                680 & 9.374 $\pm0.002$\\
                950 & 10.140 $\pm0.004$\\
                1500 & 10.575 $\pm0.002$\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \hfill
            \begin{tabular}[t]{p{1.7cm}c c}
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Group C}}\\
                \toprule
                P (PSIG) & $U\ (\frac{BTU}{hr\ ft^2\ ^\circ F})$\\
                &\\
                &\\
                \midrule
                15 & 104.1 $\pm0.1$\\
                30 & 111.6 $\pm0.1$\\
                &\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \hfill
            \begin{tabular}[t]{p{1.7cm}c c}
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Group D}}\\
                \toprule
                $\dot{V}$ ($\frac{m^3}{s}$)                                 & $U\ (\frac{BTU}{hr\ ft^2\ ^\circ F})$ \\
                &\\
                &\\
                \midrule
                $2.05 \cdot 10^{-4}$ & 1616\\
                $3.79 \cdot 10^{-4}$ & 3138\\  
                &\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
```

Comment: Why even do this in three tables? Why not just one?

Comment: It will be a huge table

Answer (score 1):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec        = {X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]X[c,m]},
cell{1}{1,3,5} = {c=2}{},
row{1}         = {font=\bfseries},
hline{2,Z}     = {1-2}{wd=.08em,leftpos=-1,rightpos=-1,endpos=true},
hline{2,Z}     = {3-4}{wd=.08em,leftpos=-1,rightpos=-1,endpos=true},
hline{2,Z}     = {5-6}{wd=.08em,leftpos=-1,rightpos=-1,endpos=true},
hline{3}       = {1-2}{wd=.05em,leftpos=-1,rightpos=-1,endpos=true},
hline{3}       = {3-4}{wd=.05em,leftpos=-1,rightpos=-1,endpos=true},
hline{3}       = {5-6}{wd=.05em,leftpos=-1,rightpos=-1,endpos=true},
}
Group A              &                                       & Group C  &                                       & Group D                     &                                       \\
Agitator speed (rpm) & $U\ (\frac{BTU}{hr\ ft^2\ ^\circ F})$ & P (PSIG) & $U\ (\frac{BTU}{hr\ ft^2\ ^\circ F})$ & $\dot{V}$ ($\frac{m^3}{s}$) & $U\ (\frac{BTU}{hr\ ft^2\ ^\circ F})$ \\
680                  & 9.374 $\pm~0.002$                     & 15       & 104.1 $\pm~0.1$                       & $2.05 \cdot 10^{-4}$        & 1616                                  \\
950                  & 10.140 $\pm~0.004$                    & 30       & 111.6 $\pm~0.1$                       & $3.79 \cdot 10^{-4}$        & 3138                                  \\
1500                 & 10.575 $\pm~0.002$                    &          &                                       &                             &                                       \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me. I am listing the changes I made below.

1. Added the colortbl package and `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}`
   `\setlength\minrowclearance{1.5pt}` commands to the preamble to fix row height.
2. Moved the (rpm) text to the second row instead of keeping it to the first.
3. Removed one of the empty lines just before the midrule in the second and third table. This is to ensure that all tables have the same number of rows.

```
\documentclass[letter,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} %for toprule, midrule and bottomrule
\usepackage{colortbl} %for minirowclearance

%fix row height for all tables
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5} 
\setlength\minrowclearance{1.5pt}


\begin{document}



\begin{table}
\centering
        \footnotesize
            \begin{tabular}[t]{p{2.5cm}c c}
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Group A}}\\
                \toprule
                Agitator speed  & $U\ (\frac{BTU}{hr\ ft^2\ ^\circ F})$\\
                (rpm)&&\\

                \midrule
                680 & 9.374 $\pm0.002$\\
                950 & 10.140 $\pm0.004$\\
                1500 & 10.575 $\pm0.002$\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \hfill
            \begin{tabular}[t]{p{1.7cm}c c}
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Group C}}\\
                \toprule
                P (PSIG) & $U\ (\frac{BTU}{hr\ ft^2\ ^\circ F})$\\
                &\\

                \midrule
                15 & 104.1 $\pm0.1$\\
                30 & 111.6 $\pm0.1$\\
                &\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \hfill
            \begin{tabular}[t]{p{1.7cm}c c}
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Group D}}\\
                \toprule
                $\dot{V}$ ($\frac{m^3}{s}$) & $U\ (\frac{BTU}{hr\ ft^2\ ^\circ F})$ \\
                &\\

                \midrule
                $2.05 \cdot 10^{-4}$ & 1616\\
                $3.79 \cdot 10^{-4}$ & 3138\\  
                &\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

After almost two years ...

Your problem I would solve by:

- merge all tree table in one table.
- for table rules use `\cmidrule`
- for shorter code in `U` columns define new SI unit
- for shorter writing of uncertainty exploit features of `siunitx` package

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \DeclareSIUnit\U{hr\,ft^2\,^{\circ}F}
    \sisetup{uncertainty-mode = separate}
    \centering    
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[c, si={table-format=4.0}]   Q[c, si={table-format=2.4(3)}]
                        Q[c, si={table-format=3.3}]   Q[c, si={table-format=3.2(1)}]
                        Q[c, si={table-format=1.2e2}] Q[c, si={table-format=4.0}]
                        },
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries},
             row{1,2}= {guard},
             }
\SetCell[c=2]{c} Group A
        &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Group B
                    &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Group C                   
                                    &       \\
    \cmidrule[lr,\heavyrulewidth]{1-2}
    \cmidrule[lr,\heavyrulewidth]{3-4}
    \cmidrule[lr,\heavyrulewidth]{5-6}
{Agitator speed\\ (rpm)} 
        & {$U$\\ $\left(\frac{BTU}{\unit{\U}}\right)$} 
            & {P\\ (PSIG)} 
                    & {$U$\\ $\left(\frac{BTU}{\unit{\U}}\right)$}
                        & {$\dot{V}$\\ (rpm)}
                                    & {$\left(\frac{BTU}{\unit{\U}}\right)$}
                                            \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{1-2}
    \cmidrule[lr]{3-4}
    \cmidrule[lr]{5-6}
 680    &   9.374(2) 
            & 15    & 104.1(1)
                        & 2.05e-4   & 1616  \\
 950    & 10.140(4) 
            & 30    & 111.6(1)
                        & 3.79e-4   & 3138  \\
1500    & 10.575(2) 
            &       &   &           &       \\
    \cmidrule[lr,\heavyrulewidth]{1-2}
    \cmidrule[lr,\heavyrulewidth]{3-4}
    \cmidrule[lr,\heavyrulewidth]{5-6}
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines shows text block borders)

Answer (score 0):

If you like it complicated, you can do it with `\vphantom`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
%\errorcontextlines=10000

\ExplSyntaxOn
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% A dumb copy of \int_step_function:nN where instead of a single function you
% can supply several tokens where the number is appended to

\cs_new:Npn \int_step_AppendToTokens:nn {\int_step_ToTokens:nnnn {1}{1}}

\cs_new:Npn \int_step_ToTokens:nnnn #1#2#3 { \exp_after:wN \__int_step:wwwn
\int_value:w \__int_eval:w #1\exp_after:wN ;\int_value:w \__int_eval:w
#2\exp_after:wN ;\int_value:w \__int_eval:w #3; }

\cs_new:Npn \__int_step:wwwn #1;#2;#3;#4 { \int_compare:nNnTF
{#2}>\c_zero_int {\__int_step:Nwnnn >}{\int_compare:nNnTF {#2}=\c_zero_int
{\__kernel_msg_expandable_error:nnn {kernel}{zero-step}{#4}\prg_break:
}{\__int_step:Nwnnn <}}#1;{#2}{#3}{#4}\prg_break_point: }

\cs_new:Npn \__int_step:Nwnnn #1#2;#3#4#5 { \if_int_compare:w
#2#1#4\exp_stop_f: \prg_break:n \fi: #5{#2}\exp_after:wN \__int_step:Nwnnn
\exp_after:wN #1\int_value:w \__int_eval:w #2+#3;{#3}{#4}{#5} }
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\cs_new:Npn \vphantoms #1#2 {
  \int_step_AppendToTokens:nn {\tl_count:n {#1}} {\dovphantom:nn{#1}}
  \tl_item:nn {#1} {#2}
}
\cs_new:Nn \dovphantom:nn {\vphantom{\tl_item:nn {#1} {#2}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newlength\scratchylength

\usepackage{booktabs, amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \footnotesize
  \noindent
  \def\phantomtable#1#2{%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{lr}
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{%
          \vphantoms{{Group A}{Group C}{Group D}}{#1}%
        }}%
      \\
      \toprule
        \vphantoms{%
          {\settowidth\scratchylength{Agitator}%
           \parbox[t]{\scratchylength}{%
             Agitator speed%
             % Do a \hfill at the begin of the new line if line is broken here:
             \nobreak\penalty 50 \space\hskip 0pt plus -1fill\relax\hbox{}\nobreak\hfill
             (rpm)%
           }%
          }%
          {\settowidth\scratchylength{P (PSIG)}%
           \parbox[t]{\scratchylength}{P (PSIG)}}%
          {\settowidth\scratchylength{$\dot{V}$ ($\frac{\text{m}^3}{\text{s}}$)}%
           \parbox[t]{\scratchylength}{$\dot{V}$ ($\frac{\text{m}^3}{\text{s}}$)}}%
        }{#1}%
      &%
        $U$ $\left(\frac{BTU}{\text{hr\,$\text{ft}^2$\,$^{\circ}$F}}\right)$%
      \\
      \midrule
        \vphantoms{{680}{15}{$2.05 \cdot 10^{-4}$}}{#1}%
      &%
        \vphantoms{{9.374 $\pm0.002$}{104.1 $\pm0.1$}{1616}}{#1}%
      \\%
        \vphantoms{{950}{30}{$3.79 \cdot 10^{-4}$}}{#1}%
      &%
        \vphantoms{{10.140 $\pm0.004$}{111.6 $\pm0.1$}{3138}}{#1}%
      \\%
        \vphantoms{{1500}{}{}}{#1}&\vphantoms{{10.575 $\pm0.002$}{}{}}{#1}%
      \\%
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    #2%
  }%
  \phantomtable{1}{\nobreak\hskip .75em plus 1 fill}%
  \phantomtable{2}{\nobreak\hskip .75em plus 1 fill}%
  \phantomtable{3}{}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know what `P` and `PSIG` are about. Maybe some of them need to be typeset in mathmode.